# Xamarin Forms App Remote Connection to Mac OSX for iOS testing

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to connect my Xamarin Forms app (which has been tested on Android only for the time being) with a Mac machine for iOS testing. The Windows 10 machine seems to be connecting to the Mac, in fact I always see the message saying successfully connected to the Mac computer name. After 5 seconds, Visual Studio simply closes on the Windows Machine with no error dialog. I do not see anything happening on the Mac.

I cant seem to find any visual studio logs (I also tried to open Visual studio in log mode). In the Windows Event viewer, however, I find this in the Applications log.

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
at System.Enum+EnumResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind, System.String, System.Object)
at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(System.Type, System.String, Boolean, EnumResult ByRef)
at System.Enum.Parse(System.Type, System.String, Boolean)
at Xamarin.MacDev.PropertyListFormat+XmlFormat+Context.ReadObjectHead()
```

**Windows Platform Details**

> Operating System: Windows 10 PRO Version 1803 (OS Build: 17134.165)
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.7.4
>
> Microsoft.NET Framework Version 4.7.03056
>
> Xamarin - 4.10.10.2 (35a01d8dc)
>
> Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.MAC SDK - 11.12.0.4 (64fece5)

**Mac OSX Platform Details**

> Operating System: macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6
>
> Visual Studio Community 2014 for Mac Version 7.5.4 (build 3)
>
> Runtime: Mono 5.10.1.57 (2017-12/ea8a24b1bbf) (64-bit) GTK+ 2.24.23
>   (Raleigh theme) Xamarin.MAC 4.4.1.178 (master/ eeaeb7e60
>
> Package version: 510010057
>
> Xamarin Profiler Version 1.6.2
>
> Apple Developer Tools  X Code 9.4.1 (14161) Build 9F2000
>
> Xamarin.MAC Version 4.4.1.193 (Visual Studio Community)
>
> Xamarin.iOS Version 11.12.0.4 (Visual Studio Community)
>
> Xamarin Inspector Version 1.4.0

Comment: did you make sure that xcode is  up to date  ? that one always gets me

Comment: Yes, I have just installed everything afresh, as this is the first time trying to remotely connect to Mac from a Xamarin Forms app. So everything should be up to date!